# Better way to reformat dates in Excel

Tags: excel

I currently am pulling data onto excel that looks like the following: 
[image]

I am using the following formula to convert the date to look like this: [image]

**Formula**
=`VLOOKUP(LEFT([@[Date attending]],3),Parameters!$O$1:$P$13,2,0)&"/"&MID([@[Date attending]],5,2)&"/"&MID([@[Date attending]],9,4)*1`

*Quick overview of formula above:*

---

The LEFT refers to the first image (Aug 7, 2019) and grabs the "Aug". The Parameters tab has a helper column that converts my month to a number. So Aug will convert to 8. The rest of the formula basically is just concatenating parts of the "Aug 7, 2019".

Obviously this has it's problems. As you can see above this is also grabbing the comma in the string (Aug 7, 2019). [image] So every time this happens I change the formula to the following: (TLDR; I just change one of the MID formulas to grab one character instead of 2)

---

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT([@[Date attending]],3),Parameters!$O$1:$P$13,2,0)&"/"&MID([@[Date attending]],5,1)&"/"&MID([@[Date attending]],9,4)*1
```

Result of changed formula: [image]

Comment: To be clear the `Aug 7, 2019 at 6:30 PM` is a string, not a formatted date correct? Or is the cell a time, formatted as `mmm d, yyyy at H:MM AM/PM`?  As a quick fix, what if you just did `=SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(LEFT([@[Date attending]],3),Parameters!$O$1:$P$13,2,0)&"/"&MID([@[Date attending]],5,2)&"/"&MID([@[Date attending]],9,4)*1,",","")`?

Comment: Yes! Aug 7, 2019 at 6:30 PM is just a string!

Comment: @BruceWayne thank you this definitely worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need parameters. Especially since your date (except for the **at** word), is truly unambiguous.

Just use `DATEVALUE`:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT([@[Date attending]],FIND(" at",[@[Date attending]])))
```

or

```
=INT(SUBSTITUTE([@[Date attending]],"at ",""))
```

If you want to also have the time, then:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT([@[Date attending]],FIND(" at",[@[Date attending]])))+ TIMEVALUE(MID([@[Date attending]],FIND("at",[@[Date attending]])+3,99))
```

or, simpler:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE([@[Date attending]],"at ","")
```

If, for some reason, you need the month number, wrap the above with the `MONTH` function.

Format the results however you  wish.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DATEVALUE()` and `SUBSTITUTE()`:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE([VLOOKUP FORMULA HERE],"at",""))
```

[image]

And `B5` is formatted as `m/d/yy`.

The alternative (as I commented) is to simply remove the comma from your `VLOOKUP()` result. However, depending on what you want to *do* with this result, you might want it actually formatted as date, which is what `DATEVALUE()` does.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called DATE, with 3 parameters (DATE(year,month,day)) that'll do the conversion for you.

So I guess you can have a workaround like:

`DATE(MID([@[Date attending]],9,4)*1,VLOOKUP(LEFT([@[Date attending]],3),Parameters!$O$1:$P$13,2,0),MID([@[Date attending]],5,2))`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

With **text** in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" at",A1)-1))
```

and apply the proper format:

[image]

This way you avoid having to translate `Aug` into `8`.